# Error loading driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, driver

I`m trying to connect to a MySQL database, but I have the following error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Someone have any Idea about what to do? THanks a lot! Here is my source code:

```
package simpleDB;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class getConnection {
    public Connection con = null;
    public Statement statement = null;
    public String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public String username = "root", password = "****";
    static String dbname = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/biblio";
    String sql = "select * from autores";
    String dbtime;

    public void Connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbname, username, password);
            statement = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Database connection established");
            System.out.println("capturing from database");
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                dbtime = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println(dbtime);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("nada feito: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

package simpleDB;

import simpleDB.*;

public class mainDB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getConnection conn = new getConnection();
        conn.Connect();
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong, I've been trying a lot of different codes, but I couldn't do it work...

Comment: The error message definitely is not `error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. Is the classpath setup correctly?

Comment: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` is not an error...

Comment: I really, really, really hope you didn't post your real password up there...

Comment: Did u import mysql connector properly?

Comment: That's not an error, at all. Could you post the StackTrace?

Comment: Guys, he just ignorantly printed `e.getMessage()` of a `ClassNotFoundException` instead of throwing the whole `e` altogether. The JDBC driver JAR file is very definitely missing in the runtime classpath. @user2730645, in order to get the right answer, you'd need to tell how exactly you're executing this program. Then we can tell how to set the runtime classpath right for that way of executing the program.

Answer (score 1):

you have to make sure the jar containing com.mysql.jdbc.Driver is added to your classpath

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you don't have the MySQL driver JDBC JAR in your CLASSPATH when you run.  There's not enough information to tell.  Show how you invoke this class.  Do you know how to use the java.exe command line tool?